# Is it ok to do one large join before MapGroupsWithState to get all the data (most of which isn't needed by MapGroupsWithState)?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join, spark-structured-streaming

I have two options:

I can do one join which fetches 20 columns from the same table. But only 5 of those columns is needed by MapGroupsWithState.

Or I can join and retrieve 5 columns, and then do mapgroupswithstate, then retrieve the other 15 columns.

Which of those  is better? Because each group within mapgroupswithstate will have 15 columns which will have redundant data which is getting passed over and over again. Instead I should just get the output and then join it to get those 15 columns, so they are only retrieved once. Is it less expensive to do two joins than to store redundant state?